# How to get 'messageSource' in src/groovy correctly?

Tags: spring, grails, internationalization

I need to get the `messageSource` in a class in `src\groovy`. This class is used in `UrlMappings.groovy`, and at the stage I'm using this class the application is not completely started yet.

Currently I'm using the following and it works:

```
MessageSource messageSource = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean('messageSource')
String message = messageSource.getMessage("code", null, "default", locale)
```

But the `ApplicationHolder` is deprecated, is there a way to achieve the same goal without using `ApplicationHolder`?

//I'm using Grails 2.0.1

Comment: The recommended way seems to be http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017

Comment: @Alison Thanks for the link, I've got it working with this. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way seems to be http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017

I.e. create a singleton bean in `src/groovy` which implements `ApplicationContextAware`, and then configure it's `factoryMethod` attribute in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`.

Answer (score 8):

From my limited experience, I found that the simplest approach to get the `messageSource` in a POGO is simply:

```
Holders.applicationContext.getBean("messageSource")
```

The other approaches I tried (implementing `MessageSourceAware` or adding `@Component`/`@Autowired` annotations) caused other complications.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
grails.util.GrailsWebUtil.currentApplication().mainContext.messageSource
```

Comment: add to class property: 
  @Autowired 
  protected ValidationTagLib validationTagLib
and use as <g:message .../>

Answer (score -1):

I never like using Singletons which is what Holders, GrailsWebUtil, etc are doing.  Instead you can just have grailsApplication injected in your service by doing:

```
class SomeService {
   def grailsApplication
   ...
}
```

Then use that to get a message rendered:

```
String message = grailsApplication.mainContext.getMessage(err, Locale.getDefault()).
```

Viola take any FieldError, ObjectError, or code and render a message from it.

Comment: Services are not living in src/groovy